Angular - ScrollIntoView, scolling to elements inconsistenty to different heights in scrollable modal
I have a modal, and anchor tags inside them.
When I navigate from a separate page, to the modal, depending on the element chosen, the scrollIntoView function works, but it inconsistently scrolls different elements to different heights. (The same elements are scrolled to the same position, but different elements scroll to different heights...some even barely scroll into the modal)
I'm using the
this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
  if(fragment) {
    const element = document.getElementById(fragment);
    console.log(element)
    if (element) {
      element.style.scrollMarginTop = "0px";
      element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'});
    }
  } else {
    this.topOfPage()?.nativeElement?.scrollIntoView();
  }
})

Any ideas?
I've noticed that the lower the anchor is on the page, the less is scrolls into view. E.g the bottom most anchor comes up 50% up the page, but the first anchor comes up to 95% up the page.
(when I say page, I really mean modal, as that has the scrollable element)
UPDATE
  public constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      this.roundedContainers();
      untracked(() => {
        this.scrollToContainer('+55.0px');
      });
    });
  }

This sort of fixed it, no idea why, but it definitely needs a time delay
 private scrollToContainer(offset: string): void {
    // emits once, so no need to unsubscribe
    this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
      if(fragment) {
        const element = document.getElementById(fragment);
        if (element) {
          element.style.scrollMarginTop = offset;
          setTimeout(function() {
            element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'});
          }, 250);
          console.log(fragment)
        }
      } else {
        this.topOfPage()?.nativeElement?.scrollIntoView();
      }
    })
  }

